# Kendo UI - MultiSelect replace dynamically created dataSource from external file

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-multiselect

How can I replace the Kendo UI MultiSelect dataSource values from external .js file...

**PS**: Actual values are coming from `index.html` file like below:

**index.html**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="city_fields initi-select-218" id="test">
</select>

var data = [
     "New Jersey",
     "San Francisco",
     "Las Vegas",
     "Chicago",
     "Los Angeles",
     "New York"
];

jQuery(".city_fields").kendoMultiSelect({
  dataSource: data,
  filter: "contains",
});
```

Above values I am trying to replace from init.js (external) file as below...

**init.js**

**Tried Option 1:**

```
var newData = ["Delhi",  "Bangalore"];
jQuery(".initi-select-218").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource: newData,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select",
});
```

**Tried Option 2:**

```
var newData = ["Delhi", "Bangalore"];
$("#test").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataSource: newData,
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select",
}); 
$("#test").setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: newData }));
```

**Tried Option 3:**

```
var newData = ["Delhi",  "Bangalore"];
var multiselect = $("#test").data("kendoMultiSelect");
multiselect.setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: newData }));
```

For Option 2 & 3, I am getting error as

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setDataSource is not a function`...

But still, it is taking the values from `index.html` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have jquery selector by css class. kendo `multiselect` apply same classes to wrapper also.

```
<div class="k-widget k-multiselect k-header city_fields initi-select-218" unselectable="on" title="" style="">
    ...
    <select multiple="multiple" class="city_fields initi-select-218" data-role="multiselect" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" style="display: none;">
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

Use `id` attribute instead:

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple" class="city_fields initi-select-218"></select>
<script>
    $("#multiselect").kendoMultiSelect({...});
    var multiselect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    ...
</script>
```

**Update** working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/iHoDU/2

Comment: Thanks **@Gene R**... but still it is not working... instead I am getting error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDataSource' of undefined`

Comment: for below code:

`<select multiple="multiple" accesskey="w" class="input-medium city_fields initi-select-218" id="test"></select>
var newData = ["Delhi",  "Bangalore"];

var multiselect = $("#test").data("kendoMultiSelect");
multiselect.setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: newData }));`

Comment: @Reddy you need init multiselect first:`$("#test").kendoMultiSelect({...});`

Comment: Hi **Gene R**... tried again without luck though... I have updated the question with Tried options... please help me out :(

Comment: **@Gene R**... thanks... But the issue is: it is working great if both (data and newData) coming from same place, whereas it is not working if newData coming from external file :(

Comment: @Reddy you need include your external js file after multiselect is initialized. I tested myself and it works.

Comment: **@Gene R**.. yes, I am doing the same.. adding the external file just before `</body>` tag... relevant code is above of external file